# Авторизация сокетами

Tags: php, moodle

**Всем привет!**

Задача: быстрая авторизация на moodle сайте. Используя сокеты, пробовал передать логин и пароль.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$url = "localhost/login/index.php";
$data = "username=".urlencode("user")."&password=".urlencode("password");

$fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if ($fp)
{
  $out  = "POST /login/index.php HTTP/1.1\n";
  $out .= "Host: {$host}\n";
  $out .= "Referer: {$url}/\n";
  $out .= "User-Agent: firefox\n";
  $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
  $out .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\n\n";
  $out .= $data."\n\n";

  fputs($fp, $out);
  while($gets=fgets($fp,2048))
  {
    print $gets;
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

В блоке Пользователи на сайте появился мой user. Но проблема в том, что я не авторизировался.

Для решения етой задачи, думаю, необходимо, чтобы php принял куки от moodle сайта и послал браузеру. А Вы как считаете?

**Спасибо за ответы.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чем [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php) не угодил? И куки сохранит и ответы прочитает... Да и просто удобнее...

Да, скорее всего куки надо, посмотрите firebugом, что сайт возвращает после авторизации...